# mysql can be connect locally but only remotely

Tags: mysql

I have a **tomcat 8** webserver and try to connect local **mysql 5.7**, but having following error:

Caused by:

```
SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server
```

I googled and people suggested to update the password and I did as well, however doesn't work for me.

What I did

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password'

flush privileges;
```

Currently I can only use public ip address to connect back to the local database....

Comment: The exception sounds to me like there is some configuration problem with connection pooling, either on the MySQL or Tomcat side, or maybe both.  So, I would probably start by looking into that.

Comment: Yeah, that's not the error message for bad permissions / no perms to remote connect, which is what those people were trying to fix. I would assume this to be on Tomcat's end, personally

Comment: for fuck sake after I restarted the instance, the local address works. I don't know why it didn't work because I tried to restart the process. I believe the ALTER user sql does work.

Answer (score 0):

MYSQL changed the password storage method starting with version 4.1. If your client is trying to connect with the old way and the server has the password stored in the new way, then you will get that error message. In order to fix that, you have 2 choices:

- check the settings on your tomcat server
- change the password hash in the mysql server, to be compatible with versions pre-4.1

If you want to change the password to use the old hashing type, use a command like:

```
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR
-> 'some_user'@'some_host' = OLD_PASSWORD('new_password');
```

After that you have to start your mysql server with `old_passwords` system variable set to 1

On the other hand, I think that the best way of resolving this will be to set the client to use the proper way of connecting to the mysql server.

If you use PHP for connecting to the server, check if you use `mysql` of `mysqli` library. I think that only `mysqli` library uses the new way of managing connections.